# PHP/Java MYSQL Thesaurus Database

Tags: java, php, mysql, thesaurus

I'm looking for a thesaurus that is free and can be easily dump into a mysql database and accessed using php or java to get related words and meanings, I have been searching, I saw mobysaurus but I dont think it can be dumped into a database since it's desktop based. Please help.

Answer (score 0):

I would highly recommend [Wordnet](http://wordnet.princeton.edu/). All synonymous words will share the same definition.

Here is a SQL version: [WNSQLBuilder](http://wnsqlbuilder.sourceforge.net/)